# Customizing Matrix View - Add rows for Net Income/Expenses

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, row

I've been trying different methods to get Net Expenses to show in the 2nd level under Utility Expenses and Utility Income as a new row for each project code. I thought building a new table with SUMMARIZE would work, but it's just not working. Hoping you fine folks can help me.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMO8r.png)

Creating new measures, creating new columns, creating new tables.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would have sworn that the solution to this problem lies in having a properly designed dimension table that creates account hierarchies and groups. I'd look for Imke Feldmann stuff. She's the BIAccountant, so...